# Overflow hidden doesn't work on firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, overflow

Yesterday i check that one highlights products slide that i have in the home of one webpage is not property vertical aligned only on firefox, it works fine on IE and Chrome.

I was searching info and i find a lot of many years ago bugs on FF. I try a few solutions i find but no one works.

```
<div id="feature-wrap-container">
    <div id="feature_wrap">
        <div id="scrollable">
           //a list of element floating left
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#feature-wrap-container{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 260px;
}

#feature_wrap {
 width: 960px;
 height: 260px;
 overflow:hidden;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#scrollable {
 height:100%;
}
```

On chrome and IE the div is center on the window and in firefox the feature_wrap align to right and make the window bigger than the 100%.

The slide is based on: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-posts-slideshow/, but obviously modified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something, which you can show? BTW, I am able to find it good. Just reduced the width of the `#feature_wrap` and checked in firefox, and it is working. What is the issue are you facing?

Comment: Have you used "Inspect Element" to check what styles are actually in effect on the element, and where they come from. This can quickly catch surprises caused by your missing something about the cascade.

Comment: My hosting is off now...i cant continue debugging now, thanks for the help, maybe later..

Comment: But the problem is that inside the #feature_wrap the is a such list of elements to slide and in FF, with this list floating left, inside the #feature_wrap the is more width than the 960px, and i dont know why only in Firefox all go ot right.

Comment: line-height problem in previous div, bad morning for me...thanks

Answer (score 0):

See I have created a fiddle of yours [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QqGXW/), and it looks good for me in firefox. I have reduced the width of the `#feature_wrap` and checked in firefox, and it is working. What is the issue are you facing?

[image: Screenshot]

Get the full image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w444W.png).

Comment: Add inside a list of element floating left that have more width than the feature_wrap. I think that make the bug.

Comment: Can you update the fiddle and reply with the link? So that I can fix it and send you back.